# Create referenced entity if null with JPA/Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have this class:

```
public class Tenant {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @NaturalId
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, updatable = false, unique = true)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "tenant", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<User> users;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "tenant", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Role> roles;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "tenant", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, optional = false)
    private TenantLimits limits;
}
```

Where of course all referenced classes are entities. I'm able to create, update and retrieve everything from here, but since `private TenantLimits limits;` refers to an entity created after Tenant was created many of my Tenants elements don't contains any matched TenantLimits.

So my question is: How can I insert in the database a value in TenantLimits if is null when I'm going to retrieve Tenant? In Java I can easily check (of course) if the property is null and insert manually foreach retrieve, but since the retrieve of this entity is present in different places in my code I'd to have something that manage this automatically if exists

Answer (score 0):

You are telling Hibernate that Tenant.limits cannot be null by mapping it with "optional=false". It will 100% adhere to this definition. It will only create valid tenants and I assume it will throw you exceptions if the state of the database is invalid. It won't let you fix your data.

You should fix the state of your database by any other means than with this particular Hibernate mapping.

You might have to migrate in 2 steps. Let's say, make the mapping "optional=true". Then you can run a Java process to fix your data (maybe by using an entity listener). Then - change it back to "optional=false".

Comment: I can't provide Hibernate with a default instance of the object to put on db?

Comment: Your request is not very database related. It sounds like pure business logic. I don't know for sure, but I wouldn't expect such a feature from my entity mapper aka Hibernate.

Comment: I mean, you can assign default objects to attributes in Java in a very straight way.